# Change gem source to chef cookbook dependency

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

My recipe

`include_recipe 'mysql::server'`

and **mysql::server** call

```ruby
chef_gem 'mysql'
```

**chef_gem 'mysql'** use like gem source http://rubygems.org/

I need use my own gems local server.

How can I change the gem source for all chef running?

OPTION:
 I try install at first mysql gem with

```ruby
chef_gem 'mysql' do
  options "--source http://my.own.local.server/"
  version "2.9.1"
end
```

but don't work.

Any body have other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're severals things out of your question:

- You should use resource **gem_package** to install gem for system-wide because `chef_gem` is used for installing gem for dedicated chef usage. see this quote from http://docs.opscode.com/resource_gem_package.html:

> Use the **chef_gem** resource to install gems into the instance of Ruby that is dedicated to the chef-client. Use the **gem_package** resource to install all other gems (i.e. install gems system-wide).

- install gem (and its dependencies) from other source than `http://rubygems.org/`

For example:

```
gem_package "mysql" do
  options("--clear-sources --source http://my.own.local.server/")
  action :install
  version "2.9.1"
end
```

Comment: Ok, @shawnzhu, thanks. Good job. But, what can I do if my cookbook depends on other that have **chef_gem 'mysql'** code and I don't have access to http://rubygems.org/

Comment: You can change the configuration of ruby gem for chef by adding a new source instead of rubygems.org only. Run `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources` to manage sources of ruby gems for embedded gems. for example: `gem sources -a http:/my.own.local.server/`

Comment: I think it was that Michel ask!! @shawnzhu